# Allow bundle to extend asset configuration of Assetic

Tags: symfony, configuration, twig, assets, assetic

I'm currently struggling with this requirement: We've got a modular app which where modules can be enabled by the customer on demand. Each module is a bundle. Now we've got some kind of dashboard where I'd like to inject assets (JS/CSS) based on the modules/bundles installed. In addition I'd like to merge those files into a single "dashboard.{js|css}" file so that we don't have 1 request per each bundles js and css file.

For other files we use a combination of Twig's Assetic integration and named assets, but it doesn't seem that the configuration key `assetic.assets` can be accessed publically in a bundle's extension class... which is a pity as it'd be an awesome easy way for our approach.

I also looked into a custom config/service couple to inject an asset loader into assetics `AssetManager` service... but this feels like a total overkill and I think that I simply missed something.

Any idea?

**Update 1**

I'm aiming for the following configuration:

```yaml
assetic: # Assetic Configuration
    assets:
        dashboard_js: 
            inputs:
                - '@ModuleOneBundle/Resources/public/js/dashboard.js'
                - '@ModuleTwoBundle/Resources/public/js/dashboard_dep.js'
                - '@ModuleTwoBundle/Resources/public/js/dashboard.js'
                - '@ModuleThreeBundle/Resources/public/js/dashboard.js'
```

Our customers can decide which modules they use and therefore I cannot hardcode them. So I was trying to use the `Configuration` classes, but they don't have access to what I need. I'd like to prevent to run custom build scripts to create `config.yml` files.

Comment: Hey, I'm also interested in this. Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, sadly not. I'm still running with ugly workarounds for this. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use the the assetic config for this to compile one file with all your needes for each bundle.  Maybe you can have a bunch of these entries in your config, all customized, then only call the one file that has your combination yuou need.  e.g.

```
assetic: # Assetic Configuration
    assets:
        js1combo: 
            inputs:
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js1.js'
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js2.js'
        js2combo: 
            inputs:
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js2.js'
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js3.js'
        js3combo: 
            inputs:
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js1.js'
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/js2.js'
```

in your files, only one js file needed

```
{% javascripts
    'js/js2combo.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

if it helps, i have a tool that can make your compiling tasks alot easier, you can run it once a day..  im trying to get the work out if anybody can help.  this has made my assetic life easier.  :-)

https://github.com/wolfdogg/symphAstman

Im not understanding your 2nd problem completely, but it sounds like you might want to make a service for that if its too involved the way your having to do it.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot hardcode the input files in `config.yml`. I'll update my question to show my target configuration I'm aiming for.